# $2^a+3^b-5^c$ expression possibilities

Tags: number-theory

Problem: Prove, that there are infinitely many whole numbers, which **can't** be expressed in the form $2^a+3^b-5^c$, where $a,b,c$ are whole non-negative numbers.

Although the solution is easy, I have no idea how to actually get to it. Any hints on how to approach a problem like this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please: **infinitely many**, not **infinite**.  There are no infinite whole numbers.

Comment: If $a>0$ then this is even.

Comment: The only cases where $2^a + 3^b - 5^c \equiv 1 \mod 10$ are with $a=0$ and $c=0$.

Comment: Could you provide me with some thinking process? Why did you choose mod 10, how did you get to it? Is the strategy just experimentation or how are people expected to solve this problem?

Comment: Just one idea: how would you express numbers divisible by 5, or even more: say perfect powers of $5$ ? None (perhaps with one or two exceptions) should be expressible by that formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We remark that, if $a>0$, your expression is always even.  Let us confine ourselves to odd integers, hence to the case $a=0$.

Consider then numbers of the form $2\times 3^n+1$ for 
$n≥1$.  If that number can be written in the desired form then we must have $$1+3^b-5^c=2\times 3^n+1\implies 3^b-5^c=2\times 3^n$$  Since $n≥1$ we see that $b=0$, just working $\pmod 3$.  But then we must have $$1=2\times 3^n+5^c$$ which is clearly not possible for $n≥1$ and $c≥0$.

Comment: Could you show me your thinking porcess? Why did you choose $2×3^n +1$? An easy way to prove it is by looking at reminders $mod 12$ and showing that no number in the form $12k+7$ can be expressed. How would you get to this type of solution?

Comment: The key point, to me, is that $a=0$ if your target is odd.  That removes one term.  Now we're just looking at $3^b-5^c=n$  From that form it is clear that divisibility by $3$ or $5$ is going to be a problem.  I just picked $3$ and that worked.  As an exercise, you should repeat the argument using targets like $2\times 5^m+1$.

Comment: Greatly appreciated.